# How can i manage session timeout in Microsoft Azure server in C#?

Tags: asp.net, azure

1. In-Proc session mode does not work in Windows Azure.Could you please reply the useful example?

Comment: Brother your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use an external session state provider. Here is an example using Redis Cache: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn690522.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do session management and handle the session timeout property. There are various ways to do session management in Azure, one of them (and usually, the preferred one) is to do it using Redis Cache.

There is a Nuget package which you can directly add to your project (RedisSessionStateProvider). Once this is done, you need to add a few tweaks to your web.config, and within that you set the timeout. This is what I had done in my project (setting as 1 for test):

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" timeout="1">
```

You can set your custom timeout right here.

If you want to delve deeper, more details on this session state provider is available at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690522.aspx

Hope this helps.